# Best way to migrate Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster of 2 nodes. My kafka version is 0.8.1.
I need to migrate it to a different set of servers.

Whats the best way to migrate maintaining no downtime and no data loss?

Comment: About the case when the new servers are in a new data center: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420949/migrating-a-kafka-cluster-to-new-datacenter

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the new servers and old servers live together in the same data center, the easiest way will be to add the new ones as replicas for all the existing partitions you have. Kafka will bring them in sync making them ISRs. One they are in-sync you should be able to safely shutdown the old nodes.

This of course depends on how your consumers are configured (will they automatically find the new nodes?) and which version of Kafka you're on.

Take a look at:

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_cluster_expansion
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_decommissioning_brokers

You will need to use the *kafka-reassign-partitions.sh* tool to make this happen. Test in a non-production environment first.

Comment: i am running kafka 0.8.1

Comment: What happens when we upgrade from `0.10.X` to `2.0.X`? Can we add the `2.0.X` brokers to previous cluster? Does the `message.format.version` make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use kafka mirror maker. Have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330 or https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_mirror_maker

Basically you run something like this:

```
cp /usr/lib/kafka/config/consumer.properties oldCluster.consumer.properties
cp /usr/lib/kafka/config/producer.properties newCluster.producer.properties
```

Than you set-up old cluster things, for example:

```
bootstrap.servers=clusterOldServer1.full.name:9092
auto.offset.reset=earliest
#zookeeper.connect=commentedOutZookeeperForOlderKafka
```

And than you run migrate command, which will run as "daemon":

```
time kafka-run-class kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config oldCluster.consumer.properties --producer.config newCluster.producer.properties --whitelist="topic.*regexp"
```

Comment: Note that this approach will not preserve message offsets, and so if you redirect existing consumers to the new mirrored cluster, they will not resume with the offset at which they left off. Depending on details, your consumers could end up skipping or re-processing messages.

Comment: Is there any way to not let consumers reprocess the messages when they are connected to the new cluster.?