# Migrating a kafka cluster to new datacenter

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a small 3 node kafka cluster with about 20GB data per node. We're moving to a new datacenter so need to move the cluster; both DC's are currently operational.

Round trip times between the DC's are:

```
35 packets transmitted, 35 received, 0% packet loss, time 34048ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.265/14.883/86.126/22.047 ms
```

Would it be practical to set up new nodes in the new DC, replicate to them and then remove the old nodes? Would the latency be too high?

I'd appreciate your advice. If this method wouldn't work, I welcome suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use MirrorMaker to replicate data between clusters and set a moderately larger value for all configs that relate to the timeout.

Comment: Note that this approach will not preserve message offsets, and so if you redirect existing consumers to the new mirrored cluster, they will not resume with the offset at which they left off. Depending on details, your consumers could end up skipping or re-processing messages.